# Powershell download multiple files in different folders from an REST Api

Tags: powershell

I have multiple date stamped folders and static filenames on a server that I need to recursively download using powershell from an REST Api.

For example the source will be:

https://servername/rest/ofscore/v1/folders/20241204/file1.xml

locations of additional files and folders below.

20241204/file1.xml
20241204/file2.xml

20241205/file1.xml
20241205/file2.xml

etc.

I have the following code, but I need to be able to recursively retrieve these files as the date increments and load them into a local folder.

```
$url = "https://caccteqjx2.test.etadirect.com/rest/ofscCore/v1/folders/dailyExtract/folders/2024-03-05/"
$file = "file1.xml"
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Credentials = Get-Credential
$wc.DownloadFile($url, $file)



# List of file URLs to download
$Urls = @(
    "https://caccteqjx2.test.etadirect.com/rest/ofscCore/v1/folders/dailyExtract/folders/2024-03-05/"
   
)
 
# Destination folder
$DestinationFolder = "c:\temp"
 
# Ensure the destination folder exists
If (-not (Test-Path $DestinationFolder)) {
    New-Item -Path $DestinationFolder -ItemType Directory
}
 
# Download each file
$TotalUrls = $urls.Count
$Counter = 0
ForEach($URL in $Urls)
{
    $FileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($url)  # Extract file name from URL
    $DestinationPath = Join-Path -Path $DestinationFolder -ChildPath $FileName
 
    # Display main progress
    Write-Progress -Activity "Downloading files ($($Counter+1) of $TotalUrls)" -Status ("Downloading " + $FileName) -PercentComplete (($Counter / $TotalUrls) * 100)
 
    # Download file with sub-progress bar for individual file download
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $destinationPath
    $Counter++
}
 
Write-Progress -Activity "Downloading files" -Completed -Status "All files downloaded!"
Write-Host "All files downloaded successfully!" -ForegroundColor Green
```

Comment: It would help if you can narrow down your question - which part of your script isn’t working properly? What currently happens in that part, and what do you expect to happen in that part?

Comment: At present the script only downloads one folder and file using this part:     ``` # List of file URLs to download
$Urls = @(
    "https://caccteqjx2.test.etadirect.com/rest/ofscCore/v1/folders/dailyExtract/folders/2024-03-05/"
   
)```  I need it to recursively download the latest folder containing the files.